# Agrupar células case when vazias sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, case, when

Estou fazendo uma consulta na base de dados para saber em qual filial o cliente pagou uma parcela e qual o valor normal e de juros que foram pagos.

O valor da parcela é a operação 3 no banco e o valor de juros é a operação 59.

Segue o sql abaixo:

```
select 
adm_fili.cd_filial,
fin_lcto.nr_titulo,
fin_lcto.sufixo as parcela,
(case when (fin_lcto.cd_operacao=3)
 then fin_lcto.vl_operacao end) as vl_baixas,
 (case when (fin_lcto.cd_operacao=59)
 then fin_lcto.vl_operacao end) as vl_juros,
fin_lcto.dt_vcto as Vencimento
from fin_lcto
join adm_fili on (fin_lcto.cd_filial=adm_fili.cd_filial)

where cd_operacao in(3,59)
and fin_lcto.dt_lancamento between '2018-11-01' and '2018-11-01'

order by nr_titulo
```

Da maneira como estou fazendo o banco retorna o resultado assim

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber se há algum jeito de agrupar as colunas de valor de parcela e valor de juros na mesma linha.

Já tentei usar group by mas não funcionou.

Se alguém souber de uma solução agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se utilizar o `GROUP BY` acho que consegue o que pretende:

```
SELECT      adm_fili.cd_filial
        ,   fin_lcto.nr_titulo
        ,   fin_lcto.sufixo                             AS parcela
        ,   SUM(CASE    WHEN fin_lcto.cd_operacao = 3
                        THEN fin_lcto.vl_operacao END)) AS vl_baixas
        ,   SUM(CASE    WHEN fin_lcto.cd_operacao = 59
                        THEN fin_lcto.vl_operacao END)  AS vl_juros
        ,   fin_lcto.dt_vcto                            AS Vencimento
FROM        fin_lcto
JOIN        adm_fili on fin_lcto.cd_filial = adm_fili.cd_filial
WHERE       cd_operacao in (3, 59)
        AND fin_lcto.dt_lancamento BETWEEN '2018-11-01' AND '2018-11-01'
GROUP BY    adm_fili.cd_filial
        ,   fin_lcto.nr_titulo
        ,   fin_lcto.sufixo
        ,   fin_lcto.dt_vcto
ORDER BY    nr_titulo
```

Não sei como testou antes, mas dessa forma consegue a soma dos dois campos.

Comment: Deu certo. Não tinha usado o sum para as colunas com case.